# Не видно кнопку button на iOS

Tags: html, css

На этой [странице](http://mazzmedia.ru) в самой нижней форме есть кнопка отправки формы `<button></button>`. Почему-то кнопка не видна на телефоне и планшете (iOS). Видна только левая обводка. Из-за чего это может быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На последних версиях iOS отображается корректно.

Comment: попробуйте добавить к button -  -webkit-appearance: none;

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none; было сразу добавлено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`right 25px center` - что Вы тут хотели задать?

Попробуйте:

```
background: url(../images/send_message_icon.png) right 25px no-repeat #76BEE3;
```

P.S: `background-position` *имеет 2 значения, а не 3*

Comment: background-position задан через CSS3. Отступ от правого края 25 пикселей и вертикально по центру.

Comment: Мне помогло задание 2-х значений.